# Programmatically change the uid and gid of a running external process using c

Tags: c, ios, macos, unix, process

How to programatically change the uid and gid of a running **external** process using c?

Comment: Is this actually done the same way on iOS as it is on unix systems? If not, the iOS tag should be removed. If so, wow, that's amazing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small example that includes the possibility to change uid et gid using existing user and group names:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>

// .. snip

// find user and group
struct passwd * pwd = getpwnam("new_user");
struct group * grp = getgrnam("new_group");

// not included : error checking

uid_t uid = pwd->pw_uid;
gid_t gid = grp->gr_gid;

setgid(gid);
setuid(uid);
```

**edit**: This only works for the current process

Comment: sorry,update the question just now,what i want is to change  the uid and gid of a running external process but not itself.

Comment: that's unfair :) Anyways, I'm afraid it is not normally doable.

Comment: yup,seems a little unfair,but i think it could solve my problem:)